# http-proxy-middleware - access to the static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to combine my static landing page with the express.js app (react.js single page app).

On my landing page, I set up proxy using `http-proxy-middleware` 
My server.js for the static page looks like that:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var options = {
        target: 'http://localhost:9000', // the app
        changeOrigin: true
    };
var exampleProxy = proxy(options);

app.use('/app', exampleProxy);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))

app.listen(8080);
```

The problem is that when I get to localhost:8080/app/ I have access to correct index.html, but I cannot fetch the resources, the bundle.js is being fetched like that: `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js`, but apparently it is available on localhost:9000, not 8080

How do I make it so as the app has access to its static files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the wildcard path matching of `http-proxy-middleware` module. You can implement the `app.use` without passing the path parameter.

```
app.use(proxy('/*.js', exampleProxy));
app.use(proxy('/api', exampleProxy));
```

This will serve your ".js" file through port 9000. Similarly, you can serve other assets as well by using this wildcard matching.

Comment: Thank you, is there any magic trick for taking care of the routes? it says `Location "/app/template/vintage" did not match any routes` because only `/template/vintage` exists on the single page.

Comment: You can use the pathRewrite property in proxy options. You can then rewrite any path that you want. pathRewrite: {'^/api/remove/path' : '/path'}